If $R$ is a simple f.d. $k$-algebra, $M$ a f.g. $R$-module, $E=End_R(M)$, then $\dim_k M^2=\dim_k R\dim_k E$
I'm working through Lam's A First Course in Noncommutative Rings, and I'm stuck on problem 3.7:
Show that, if $R$ is a finite dimensional simple algebra over its center $k$, $M$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, and $E=\operatorname{End}(_R M)$, then $(\dim_k M)^2=\dim_k R\cdot \dim_k E$.
In the case $R=M_n(D)$ is artinian, this isn't too bad: we can write $M=V^{\oplus m}$, where $V=D^n$ is the unique simple $R$-module. Then, $\dim_k R=n^2\dim_k D$, $\dim_k M=nm\dim_k D$, and $\dim_k E=m^2\dim_k\operatorname{End}(_R V)=m^2\dim_k D$. This is using the double centralizer property of $D$ to say $E\cong D$.
In the general case, I imagine I have to use the double centralizer property of $R$ somehow, but I'm not able to figure out how to apply it here, especially since the above case doesn't use it.
I also have the following "intuitive" argument for why this should be true:
$$\dim_k(E)=\dim_k\operatorname{Hom}_R(M, M)=\dim_k R\cdot \dim_R\operatorname{Hom}_R(M, M)=\dim_k R\cdot\dim_R(M)^2=\dim_k R\cdot\left(\frac{\dim_k M}{\dim_k R}\right)^2.$$
Any help/hints are appreciated!

So you are stuck in the case where $R$ is not artinian? This is not possible, as it is a finite dimensional algebra over a field. (if I assumed correctly that $k$ is a field)

@Mark you're right $k$ is a field (the center of a simple ring is necessarily a field, this was a previous exercise). I'll try to prove $R$ must be artinian, thanks!
